# Looking for clear and as elementary as possible sources for the construction of linearly independent vector fields on $S^n$.

Tags: vector-fields, online-resources, clifford-algebras

Specifically the construction of the vector fields using Clifford algebras. I'm looking for sources that use minimal prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

The basic reference for the subject of Clifford algebras and spin geometry appears to be [Spin Geometry](https://books.google.de/books/about/Spin_Geometry.html?id=3d9JkN8w3X8C) by H. Blain Lawson and Marie-Louise Michelsohn. The vector fields you mention are constructed in the first chapter.